# Platform android error occurs in ionic 1 framework

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

hi all i am using ionic 1 framework to build app now i add android platform but i am  not able to >ionic `cordova` build android --release command i getting error add platform to body and update `jdk` i already done that still i facing same problem here i  attached screenshot below anyone help how to solve the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When this error appeared to me, it was enough to install JDK 1.8. If it is already installed you must adjust JAVA_HOME because in your case it is pointed to version 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to download JDK 1.8
[Java SE Development Kit 8 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

In case you have doubts, I inform you that the JDK includes the JRE along with several development tools.

Make sure that the JAVA_HOME system variable points to the new PATH